# How to use Supervisor to run Websocket server on AWS Lightsail instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, websocket, node-supervisor

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/takielias/codeigniter-websocket) to add websockets to my codeigniter app. I got everything to work, but I need the websocket server to always run in the background, regardless of the CLI being open or not.
To run the server in the CLI, I run this command:

```
php index.php welcome index
```

Which gives me:

```
Running server on host 0.0.0.0:8282
Authentication activated
```

Websockets works on my app, but if I close the CLI, the server closes as well. How do I keep this running? I have Supervisor ([as suggested for Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/deploy)), but I have no idea where to go from here. I'm just running a simple PHP server (Ubuntu on AWS Lightsail), not a node one, bytheway.

Comment: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/axh1/monitoring-a-php-process-example-with-supervisor

Comment: Thanks @vuryss ! This works! I had to do a little bit of trouble shooting, so just so other know, you need to set your directory path to just be the same as your app.